# Change Highest Section Order

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, labels

The default headings are numbered down to the subsubsection level using a decimal system (<CHAPTER #>.<SECTION #>.<SUBSECTION#>.<SUBSUBSECTION #>).You can change the depth to which headings are numbered with the command
`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{#}`

In my report,my highest section should be 'SECTION' not "CHAPTER" such that now my table of contents and section headers are labeled:

[image: Broken TOC]

I need them to be labeled correctly starting with the section number (1, 2, 2.1.)

I have tried:

```
\newcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

I have also tried using the [tocvsec2 package](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocvsec2/tocvsec2.pdf) but it only defines section minimums(subsubsection) NOT maximums (Section instead of Chapter).

```
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you using unnumbered chapters (`\chapter*`) If you want a chapter number to appear as prefix for section numbers?

Comment: or do you mean you don't want sections numbered within chapters, in which case `\numberwithout{section}{chapter}` should do what you want

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want sections numbered, not chapters (1.0 not 0.1). Currently the chapter number is 0. I cannot use '/numberwithout'

Comment: It's hard to help without a full document example, but does `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` help? This should remove the chapter number attached to the section numbers.

Comment: your question is very unclear. what number do you want the first section in chapter 2 to have?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but if you don't want to use chapters at all then you should switch to a documentclass that has section as the highest level, like `article` or `scrartcl`.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks so much! I used it in the body of my text, before the section headings and it worked!